# How should this result write in php?

Tags: javascript, php

When I execute a php file it give me this result:

```
[{"title":{"0":"Offer Number 1"},"link":{"0":"https:\/\/www.domain.com\/show.php?l=0&u=8793&id=6335&tracking_id=mnn"}}]
```

the offer title is .$offeritem->title. and the URL is .$offeritem->link.

I want to make a php file that show like this result of an offer and its url.

And then I want to call them (offer title + url) via javascript using this code:

```
openVerification: function() {
                var e = this;
                jQuery.getJSON("functions/offers.php", function(t) {
                    if (!t.error) {
                        var n = "";
                        $.each(t, function(e, t) {
                            n += '\n <li class="list-group-item"><a target="_blank" href="' + offerlink[0] + '">' + title[0] + "</a></li>\n                    
                        }), i.hideAll(), i.dialog({
                            message: '\n                                                 <ul class="list-group">\n                            ' + n + '\n                        </ul>\n                                     ',
                            title: "offers",
                            closeButton: !1,
                            buttons: {
                                cancel: {
                                    label: "Cancelar",
                                    className: "btn-default",
                                    callback: function() {
                                        e.resetGenerator()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            },
```

so in short I want to make the offers.php file.

Comment: create an array in php file and use json_encode. example- echo json_encode($yourarray);

Comment: You probably should show your current php since what you need is to get it modified, as far as I can see

Comment: No it's not my php file, I just want to make one similar to it

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON OP is not efficient

```
[
  {
    "title":{"0":"Offer Number 1"},
    "link":{"0":"https:\/\/www.domain.com\/show.php?l=0&u=8793&id=6335&tracking_id=mnn"}
  }
]
```

According to me it should be

```
[
   {"title"::"Offer Number 1","link":"https:\/\/www.domain.com\/show.php?l=0&u=8793&id=6335&tracking_id=mnn"},
   {"title"::"Offer Number 1","link":"https:\/\/www.domain.com\/show.php?l=0&u=8793&id=6335&tracking_id=mnn"}
]
```

I am writting PHP code for both JSON OP:-

For 1st One:-

```
$offer[0]['title'][0] = "Offer Number 1";
$offer[0]['link'][0] = "https:\/\/www.domain.com\/show.php?l=0&u=8793&id=6335&tracking_id=mnn";
$offer[1]['title'][0] = "Offer Number 2";
$offer[1]['link'][0] = "https:\/\/www.domain.com\/show.php?l=0&u=8793&id=6335&tracking_id=mnn";
echo json_encode($offer);
```

For 2nd One:-

```
$offer[0]['title'] = "Offer Number 1";
$offer[0]['link'] = "https:\/\/www.domain.com\/show.php?l=0&u=8793&id=6335&tracking_id=mnn";
$offer[1]['title'] = "Offer Number 2";
$offer[1]['link'] = "https:\/\/www.domain.com\/show.php?l=0&u=8793&id=6335&tracking_id=mnn";
echo json_encode($offer);
```

Comment: it give me Internal Server Error

Comment: you have some problem at your end.

Comment: here is what I did: `$offeritem[0]['title'][0] = .$offeritem->title.;
  $offeritem[0]['link'][0] = .$offeritem->offerlink;
  
  echo json_encode($offer);`

Comment: you are using it wrongly  $offeritem[0] and $offeritem->title variable name is same so this is wrong  and  .$offeritem->title.; remove . from both side.

Comment: I just can't get it, can I put link here? is it legal?

Comment: here is the result of this php file: http://xboxgratis.com/functions/offers.php
I want to make like this php file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118969/discussion-between-hash717-and-rakesh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

your offers.php code should be somthing like-

```
<?php
    $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

    echo json_encode($arr); // {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
?>
```

Then your JavaScript (in this example I use jQuery):

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/yourProject/offers.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This should be a start to get PHP arrays in to your JavaScript.and your access that with index of data.